# "Peer not authenticated" with Mule S3 Connector

Tags: ssl, amazon-s3, mule, ssl-certificate, mule-studio

So I'm using Anypoint Studio to work on a mule project and when invoking the Mule S3 Connector, it keeps throwing `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated`. I've read the other threads and haven't been able to figure it out. I'm working on my localhost, not on a server. I've tried changing my jre version, adding a self-signed certificate to my version of java, and adding my aws credentials to a half dozen places.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The stacktrace looks like this:

```
INFO  2015-02-26 09:08:22,612 

[[mule_experimentation].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient: Unable to execute HTTP request: peer not authenticated
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:421) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128) ~[httpclient-4.2.jar:4.2]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:572) ~[httpclient-4.2.jar:4.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ~[httpclient-4.2.jar:4.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:151) ~[httpclient-4.2.jar:4.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:125) ~[httpclient-4.2.jar:4.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:641) ~[httpclient-4.2.jar:4.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:480) ~[httpclient-4.2.jar:4.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906) ~[httpclient-4.2.jar:4.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805) ~[httpclient-4.2.jar:4.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784) ~[httpclient-4.2.jar:4.2]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:315) ~[?:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:199) ~[?:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2994) ~[?:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.createBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:649) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.s3.simpleapi.SimpleAmazonS3AmazonDevKitImpl.createBucket(SimpleAmazonS3AmazonDevKitImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.s3.S3Connector.createBucket(S3Connector.java:119) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.s3.processors.CreateBucketMessageProcessor$1.process(CreateBucketMessageProcessor.java:143) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.s3.process.ProcessCallbackProcessInterceptor.execute(ProcessCallbackProcessInterceptor.java:18) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.s3.process.ManagedConnectionProcessInterceptor.execute(ManagedConnectionProcessInterceptor.java:68) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.s3.process.ManagedConnectionProcessInterceptor.execute(ManagedConnectionProcessInterceptor.java:21) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.s3.process.RetryProcessInterceptor.execute(RetryProcessInterceptor.java:69) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.s3.connectivity.ManagedConnectionProcessTemplate.execute(ManagedConnectionProcessTemplate.java:35) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.s3.processors.CreateBucketMessageProcessor.process(CreateBucketMessageProcessor.java:129) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:94) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:102) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:102) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:102) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.construct.DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.process(DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.java:54) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:94) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:102) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:51) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:102) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:40) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:102) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$1.process(AbstractPipeline.java:109) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:94) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:50) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:22) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:66) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:61) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$3.process(AbstractPipeline.java:207) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(SimpleMessageProcessorChain.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:50) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:22) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:66) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:61) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(SimpleMessageProcessorChain.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:50) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:22) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:66) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:61) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeEvent(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:511) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractTransportMessageProcessTemplate.routeEvent(AbstractTransportMessageProcessTemplate.java:72) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.FlowProcessingPhase$1$1.process(FlowProcessingPhase.java:76) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.FlowProcessingPhase$1$1.process(FlowProcessingPhase.java:63) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:54) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:109) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.execution.FlowProcessingPhase$1.run(FlowProcessingPhase.java:62) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.transport.TrackingWorkManager$TrackeableWork.run(TrackingWorkManager.java:267) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:286) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_75]
ERROR 2015-02-26 09:08:22,614 [[mule_experimentation].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.retry.notifiers.ConnectNotifier: Failed to connect/reconnect: Work Descriptor. Root Exception was: peer not authenticated. Type: class javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException
ERROR 2015-02-26 09:08:22,619 [[mule_experimentation].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to invoke createBucket. Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. peer not authenticated (javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException)
  sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl:421 (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLPeerUnverifiedException.html)
2. Unable to execute HTTP request: peer not authenticated (com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException)
  com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient:363 (null)
3. Failed to invoke createBucket. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.module.s3.processors.CreateBucketMessageProcessor:154 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:421)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:572)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
*********************
```

Comment: How did you resolve this prod/non-prod env?

Answer (score 0):

If as you mention you are working locally (and this actually works fine in production) what you can do is to set the following system property to instruct the amazon s3 client to not to validate the certs: `com.amazonaws.sdk.disableCertChecking`.

Comment: I've done that to get moving, but I still need a solution for the long term because I need everything to be secure.